# How to use Lodash _.template in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, lodash

Could you explain me how to use Lodash `_.template` in order to get some value from script to .html file via `{{data}}` ?

For example:

In *script.js* I set some changes to my data object and in *view.html*. I want to get changed `data` with `{{data}}`

**How to use lodash `_.template()` for this issue?**

Answer (score 0):

The lodash template function does not allow you to build templates from files (but you could do it when combined with Webpack). It has absolutely nothing to do with AngularJS templates. However in some situations it makes sense of using inside of AngularJS, like for example building a list of strings with a pattern or the like.

You compile a template string to a function you can call as often as you like with the values:

```
const executor = _.template("Hello <%= name %>, my old friend!");
console.log(executor({name: 'Alice'})); // Hello Alice, my old friend!
console.log(executor({name: 'Bob'})); // Hello Bob, my old friend!
```

You can also use conditional, loops, etc.: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#template